# Android design like shown in images below?

Tags: android

I want home page like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUYfB.png) and after selecting the category [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYqj7.png) view should overlap the homepage with slide in from right animation & slide out from left on back pressed

Comment: And what's stopping you ?

Comment: I'm new to android, I hv no idea how to do this. Help me please

Comment: Fight for your dreams!

Comment: you can search for material design navigation bar...https://www.learn2crack.com/2016/03/android-material-design-sliding-navigation-drawer.html

Comment: Thank you for help

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/index.html

For you own sake try to learn using google. That is called a navigation drawer, the blurred part is backgroundtint and backgroundtintmode, note that those are available in later APIs.